# "axios only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"?

Tags: typescript

### I have looked at several other StackOverflow questions about this error message and none of them solved my problem.

I have the following two lines in a TypeScript file, trying to import some vanilla JS:

```
import axios from 'utils/UserSessionAPIAxios';
axios.doStuff(stringArgument);
```

This is my `*.d.ts` file:

```
declare module 'utils/UserSessionAPIAxios' {
  export const someData: string;

  export type DoStuffFn = (data: string) => void;

  export default interface UserSessionAPIAxios {
    doStuff: DoStuffFn;
  }
}
```

The corresponding JS file looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const someData = 'data data data';

const userSessionAxios = axios;

userSessionAxios.doStuff = (data) => {
  // omitted
};

export default userSessionAxios;
```

Why am I getting the error `axios only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` on the line where I'm calling `doStuff` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to change your `.d.ts` file to something like:

```
declare module 'utils/UserSessionAPIAxios' {
  export const someData: string;

  export type DoStuffFn = (data: string) => void;

  export interface UserSessionAPIAxios {
    doStuff: DoStuffFn;
  }

  export const userSessionAxios: UserSessionAPIAxios;

  export default userSessionAxios;

}
```

The idea is that your default export is not the `UserSessionAPIAxios` *interface*, it's a *value* whose *type* is that interface.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: thank you so much i've been stuck on this for 9 hours of two workdays. it seems so obvious now that you point out the correct implementation.